# precompiled .libs for boost on 64 bit VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

Are there precompiled .libs for boost on 64 bit VC++ 2010?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found complete set of them at http://boost.teeks99.com/.  Starting with Boost 1.43, they include VS2010.

By complete, he means complete.  VS2003, VS2005, VS2008, VS2010.  32/64 bit + all standard build options.  Do the full install, then delete the versions you don't need.

Very painless install.  All thanks to whomever is doing the the work.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded it, but now I get the following linker errors:

1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetTickCount
1>libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_43.lib(thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetTickCount
1>libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_43.lib(thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetTickCount
1>MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetTickCount
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetProcessHeap


Kernel32.lib is in the linker path.

Comment: @user410600 - Sorry, but I need to ask the obvious question first, have you included the boost libs on the "additional dependencies" line in link property settings and have you added directory to link search path?

Comment: I found the mistake: I used Windows SDK 7.0A instead of 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

http://boost.teeks99.com/ is the best bet as photo_tom said. There is the option to download the boost binaries directly from boost's sourceforge page

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

Binaries of the most recent version of boost generally are more likely to appear there first.